# Reading and extracting useful data from a file with a loop fails to produce a list of values

Tags: python, loops, isnumeric, isalpha

I am reading a file with some data. I wish to divide the data into several categories and write these into files of their own (for example integers, like phone numbers; decimals; single words; and separate sentences).

```
def data_reading():
    data = []
    integers = []
    with open("my_lines.txt") as file:
        for row in file:
            row = row.strip().replace("\n", "")
            data.extend(row.split(","))
        for values in data:
            if values.isnumeric():
                print(values + " - integer")
                integers.extend(row.split(","))
            elif values.isalpha():
                print(values + " - alphabetical strings")
            elif values.isalnum():
                print(values + " - alphanumeric")
            else:
                print(values + " - float")          
    return integers

somethin = data_reading()
print(somethin)
```

If I am to input lines like 123, abc, Address unknown, 20.12.85, I was aiming to get 4 lists to store values and use these to write in the 4 files with separate write functions. However, now I am only storing the last float value as many times as I have lines in the data file I am reading (I was trying to get the numbers with isnumerical()). How come? I seem to be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two seperate for loops, when you put your integer into the list you already iterated over all the lines in the file, so `row` points to the last row, which is "20.12.85".

Use `integers.append(values)` instead (or `integers.append(int(values))` if you want to store an actual integer).

Like this:

```
def data_reading():
    data = []
    integers = []
    with open("my_lines.txt") as file:
        for row in file:
            row = row.strip().replace("\n", "")
            data.extend(row.split(","))
        for value in data:
            if value.isnumeric():
                print(value + " - integer")
                integers.append(value)
            elif value.isalpha():
                print(value + " - alphabetical strings")
            elif value.isalnum():
                print(value + " - alphanumeric")
            else:
                print(value + " - float")
    return integers

somethin = data_reading()
print(somethin)
```

Comment: that did it! Thank you very much.